# Setting up a password identification in Flask-Restful to work with mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, curl

and sorry in advance for a noob question.
Some background: I have little to no previous experience of working in Flask or mongoDB. Three days ago, I've been contacted by my acquaintance who said that they had an opening in their development studio, and if I would prove myself capable of learning necessary tools on short notice, they'd accept me on trainee position.
As it happens, my success was going in stops and spurts. Setting up necessary environment was the easy part.I'm using Visual Studio Code for Windows, Robo 3T and Requests module for Python(3.5) as an additional tools. The project itself uses mongoDB and Flask-RESTful API to manipulate the data in it. At the insistence of the guys from studio, I'm using curl.
The test assignment is to set up a mongoDB and Flask-RESTful API, then use the latter to store a few instances of names and passwords in the database and have GET requests made with correct name and password combo get an encrypted token; with "403" showing up in response to incorrect combo.
For the base, I'm using instructions from here:
http://salmanwahed.github.io/2015/05/01/flask-restful-mongodb-api/
After some modification, I came up with this "creative"code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_DBNAME"] = "access_db"
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')
APP_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"


class Access(Resource):
    def get(self, name=None, password=None):
        data = []
        access_info = mongo.db.access.find_one({"name": name}, {"_id": 0})
        print(access_info)
        password_info = access_info['password']
        if access_info:
            if password_info:
                return jsonify({"token": "1111111111"})
            else:
                return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized access'}), 403)
        else:
            return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized access'}), 403)


    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        if not data:
            print(data)
            data = {"response": "ERROR"}
            return jsonify(data)
        else:
            name = data.get('name')
            if name:
                if mongo.db.access.find_one({"name": name}):
                    return {"response": "name already exists."}
                else:
                    mongo.db.access.insert(data)
            else:
                return {"response": "name missing"}

    def put(self, name):
        data = request.get_json()
        mongo.db.access.update({'name': name}, {'$set': data})


    def delete(self, name):
        mongo.db.access.remove({'name': name})

class Index(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return redirect(url_for("students"))


api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Index, "/", endpoint="index")
api.add_resource(Access, "/api", endpoint="access")
api.add_resource(Access, "/api/<string:name>", endpoint="name")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

While it appears to be storing name and password, it returns "Null" while doing so, and when I attempt to pull the token it gives me this:
https://pastebin.com/86hE1CCW
Could anyone kindly point out to me why exactly password_info = access_info['password'] returns "null"(if it does that), or perhaps give suggestions/source materials for better-designed way to handle the task?

Comment: According to your logs, access_info is null, which means that it's not finding your record. Why are you passing in the condition _id = 0?

Comment: Mostly because I don't *really* understand a third of the synthaxis the Flask uses. I saw this in the original code(which works) and assumed it's the way to go.

Comment: Actually, that's a valid query structure. The `_id:0` is not a condition but part of query projection. It's saying to 'return all fields except the `_id` field'. See also [query - suppress-id-field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone kindly point out to me why exactly password_info = access_info['password'] returns "null"

This is because your `find_one` query returns no matching records. Looking at your output log, this is caused by an incorrect `curl` command for `GET`.

The use of both `curl` commands below failed to specify `name` and `password` for `GET`:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "127.0.0.1:5000/api/{"username":"progen", "password":"123123"}" 
curl -G "{\"name\": \"progen\", \"password\": \"123123\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 127.0.0.1:5000/api
```

In result, your query for `find_one` is trying to find `name` field where value is `None`. Which does not exist in your `access_db` database, thus returning no records at all.

Based on your code (without modification), you could use below `curl` instead:

```
curl -G 127.0.0.1:5000/api/progen
```

Where `progen` would be passed into `get()` as the `name` variable.

See [flask-restful: quickstart](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html) for more information.

I would also suggest that you consider adding some validations. i.e check the inputs passed in and the outputs before progressing to the next code block. 
You should think about possibilities of what could have happened in a code block.

Also, depending on your MongoDB server version, I would recommend to use the latest stable version of [PyMongo 3.4](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/)